# Setting up 2-way SSL and trusting all certs from root issuer

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate, certificate

I've got to put 2-way ssl on some laptops where each one has its own different cert. On the server, I've got to configure IIS7 to trust all client certs from the issuer, so that the different certs are all accepted. I've set my IIS7 site to 'require ssl' - 'require client certificates'. I've got the one-way SSL on the domain already configured to use a cert I obtained from GoDaddy, and that's working well. When I try to make it work with 2-way ssl, I can't get it working.

The issuer in question is the company themselves, so they issue their own certs.

So far I've been given the following by my client:

- Root .cer for issuing company
- Chained .p7b file that contains the ROOT, SUBONE and Test.cer Client
- Test.cer that came from a CSR I generated on my development machine issued by SUBONE

My question is - Where do I put everything, and what settings do I need to configure this so it works?

(client: Win7, server: 2008Server, IIS7 - all bang up to date)